# Does Visual Studio have anything like Snoop's event tracking functionality?

Tags: .net, wpf, snoop

Many of you are likely familiar with [the "Snoop" utility](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) that you can run on a WPF app and use to track all sorts of things critical to debugging WPF applications. For example, I was having difficulty determining why my `PreviewKeyDown` Event handler was not receiving preview key downs, so I fired up snoop, set the filter to only show me that, and got this nice output showing me where the event went

[image]

That's great and everything but after all this time, I'm surprised there isn't something like this integrated into Visual studio automatically.  Either in VS directly or an extension.

Is there one that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.

Visual Studio has had Live Visual tree built in for some time. It has some of the same functionality as Snoop, but you may have to go hunting for it. Bindings, events and data can be inspected and I believe updated in real time just like you can variables in code when debugging.

[image: Live Visual Tree]

Comment: Thank you for the answer I should have mentioned I've used the Live Visual Tree.  I was hoping for that nice sequential log of how the event was handled.